# Creating new record in database (Sails.js)

Tags: javascript, model, module, sails.js

I created model Pattern.js, looks this way:

```
var Pattern = {

  adapter: 'land',

  attributes: {
    name: 'STRING',
    code: 'STRING'
  }
};

module.exports = Pattern;
```

And now I have two problems:

1. I can't get access from my HomeController to this model. I tried to require it, but code fails. How to get access to the models from other files?
2. There is no method 'create' in the documentation, so what is the way to create new record using a defined model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Accessing models**

You do not have to require the model yourself, Sails does this for you.

Every model you define is available in the global scope as `Filename` (uppercase first letter) and in `sails.models.filename` (all lowercase) by default after the `orm` hook has run.

`sails` is available in the global scope too.

**Documentation**

I do not know wich docs you refer to, but [there is a `create` method available on Sails / Waterline  models](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/query-methods.md#create-criteria-callback-). In your example:

```
Pattern.create(data).exec(callback);
```

You can look up on Sails / Waterline models here:

- http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models, for v0.9
- https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs for the upcoming v0.10 release